# Change PDF result to landscape

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, mvcrazortopdf

I need to convert data from database to pdf.
I am getting the data using the specified ID.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Generate Form", "generateForm", "BuyersTask", new { id=pr })
```

When I clicked the link, it should show the data in PDF Form.

```
public ActionResult generateForm(int id = 0)
    {
        var check = db.purchaseOrders.Where(s => s.prf_Id == id).GroupBy(s => s.prf_Id).Select(s => s.FirstOrDefault());

        return new PdfActionResult(check);
    }
```

I am passing the `check` to display the data in my PDF.

How is it possible that the PDF will be in landscape form?

I really need your help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](https://github.com/andyhutch77/MvcRazorToPdf/issues/15) you can achieve what you want by using this code:

```
 return new PdfActionResult(check, (writer, document) =>
            {
                document.SetPageSize(new Rectangle(1000f, 1000f, 90));
                document.NewPage();
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for this one, but the error says that there's something to do with the arguments in PdfActionResult